# Смена устройства вывода звука по умолчанию

Tags: linux, archlinux, pulseaudio

Такая ситуация: при запуске ПК звук по умолчанию идет в колонки, игнорируя наушкники. Решается выставлением Headphones в настроках KDE. Со временем такое переключение надоедает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию стоит Line Out, как мне поставить Headphones по умолчанию?

Comment: Поставьте `pavucontrol` (если не установлена) - там можно выбрать устройство, которое будет использоваться по-умолчанию.

Comment: @МАН69К Увы, он делает тоже самое, что и "Использовать по умолчанию" в интерфейсе KDE. Ставит по умолчанию Line Out, а не Headphones

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182294/110559

Answer (score 1):

в командной строке выполните
**pacmd list-sinks**
найдите в списке индекс своей карты. например
* index: 1
   name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

в разделе ports: у этой карты - перечень возможных портов:
   ports:
   **analog-output-lineout**: Линейный выход (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
   **analog-output-headphones**: Аналоговые наушники (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)

а ниже - активный порт.
у Вас, видимо, analog-output-lineout
(если Вы ещё не переключили).
Вам нужно чтобы было analog-output-headphones.

попробуйте ввести команду
**pactl set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones**
где "1" - это индекс Вашей карты (см. вначале)
а "analog-output-headphones" - название порта аналоговых наушников (у Вас может называться по-другому)

если произошло переключение на наушники, то значит Вы всё сделали верно.
теперь нужно сохранить Ваши настройки, чтобы они не "слетели" после перезагрузки. Для этого нужно создать файл
**~/.config/pulse/default.pa**
состоящий из двух строчек:
**.include /etc/pulse/default.pa

set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones**
точка перед include обязательна.
перезагрузитесь и проверьте.
пожалуй всё.